# APFS Container Resize error code is 49153

Tags: macos-high-sierra

I'm trying to resize my Mac Partition, however I always get this error:

> APFS Container Resize error code is 49153 Error: -69606: A problem
>   occurred while resizing APFS Container structures

using the Disk Utility app or terminal with the command diskutil:

```
sudo diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 400g jhfs+ Windows 100g
```

the result is the same.
I noticed that if I create a partition < 1gb with disk utility, it does the job, how is this possible?

Comment: I'm bumping into the same issue, but this is probably the wrong place to ask this question. Might be better to post it to https://apple.stackexchange.com/ or https://superuser.com/.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you have Time Machine enabled, it might be making snapshots that prevent you from resizing the APFS container. You can list them with

`tmutil listlocalsnapshots /`

and delete them with `tmutil deletelocalsnapshots` or you can delete all of them with

`tmutil thinlocalsnapshots / 9999999999999999`

Comment: I removed all listed snapshots (now empty list), but the error remains.

Comment: Try to turn off automatic backups with time machine if you have it and run the thinlocalsnapshots command.

Comment: I managed to do the resize (without turning Time Machine off), by issuing the resize commands from the command line instead of using Disk Utility.

Comment: Note: The `thinlocalsnapshots` command takes a very long time to execute...

Comment: None of the solutions proposed worked for me on macOS Big Sur. I finally found the solution: the -69606 error seems to be related to Privacy permissions. Navigate to System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Full Disk Access and add Disk Utility with the "+".
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution @Elias, I've been battling this issue for months.

Answer (score 7):

I had Time Machine enabled/one listing for

```
tmutil listlocalsnapshots /
```

so I removed it with

```
tmutil thinlocalsnapshots / 10000000000
```

then entered Time Machine preferences, told it to Stop Automatic Backups, removed the two disks I had been backing up to then went back into Disk Utility to try the resize ... and it worked this time.

MacOS High Sierra 10.13.1 Beta with 458GB partition now reduced to 428GB and am about to increase the Bootcamp partition in Windows by 30GB :-).  Big thanks to Yifan.

Answer (score 6):

I also had the problem that TimeMachine interferes with creating new Snapshots. So this seems still to be an issue on OS X 10.13.1.
Here is the sequence I used in the terminal for the whole process:

```
sudo tmutil disable
tmutil thinlocalsnapshots / 9999999999999999
sudo diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 300g ExFAT Photos 200g
sudo tmutil enable
```

Answer (score 3):

I could not solve the problem with this. What helped in my case was using the terminal as described here:
https://www.macobserver.com/tips/deep-dive/resize-your-apfs-container/

For me the progressbar stopped at 47% for quite some time, but you can check that it is making progress in the disk utility. You will see the size of the new partition increase there.

Answer (score 3):

I worked through this with Apple Care (thanks, Samuel!):

1. Open Time Machine preferences
2. Control click on the Time Machine icon and remove the selected disk
3. Reboot
4. Open Terminal and use sudo tmutil thinlocalsnapshots / 99999999999
5. Enter password
6. Open Disk Utility and try partitioning again

Note: create the partition in the container (in Disk Utility, go to View > Show all devices)

This worked for me, and now I'm going to see if Bootcamp will play. Good luck!

Comment: Step 2 (removing the backup disks from Time Machine preferences) was key for this working for me. Without this, I think `tmutil` created a new snapshot before I got a chance to resize the disk.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I sorted the error

1. Go into the 'Time Machine' pane of the System Preferences
2. Deselect Back Up Automatically
3. Run `tmutil thinlocalsnapshots / 9999999999999999` in the Terminal
4. Reboot the machine
5. Go into the 'Time Machine' pane of the System Preferences
6. Right/Ctrl click the Time Machine drive icon
7. Click 'Don't use {drive name} for Time Machine'
8. Run `tmutil thinlocalsnapshots / 9999999999999999` for the last time in Terminal
9. Resize the disk.

Comment: This worked for me...didn't do the reboot but still worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: Cleared out the local snapshots, stopped time machine, and did the resize, all via the Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

When nothing works, as was my case, wipe the whole disk and let to the disk utility create a new partition table and all the required stuff. It worked for me. I used the same name ("APPLE SSD SM0128...blah"). After the OS installation the partition was named with the same name ("APPLE SSD SM0128...blah"), so I renamed to "Macintosh HD" and installed Windows 8.1 using basecamp normally.
Hope it helps,
bye!

Answer (score 0):

Don't partition the drive in half. Adjust the size and change the format to `Mac OS Extended (Journaled)`.